# Split screen in Kitty

Tags: terminal-emulator

I would like to split screen of my terminal (kitty). I know it's [possible](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/layouts.html?highlight=split#the-vertical-layout) but there doesn't seem to be a shortcut (pre-made or that I can add to `kitty.conf` file. I also saw an option for [typing a command](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/launch.html?highlight=launch%20hsplit#cmdoption-launch-location) but I don't understand where this command needs to be typed (and is annoying to type a command to split screen each time).

Sidenote: There is no existing tag for 'Kitty' and I can't create it either.

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As [Kitty's document](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/overview/#tabs-and-windows) specifies, you can have both tabs and split screens (Kitty calls them "windows").

---

**Tab:**

New tab: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> (also <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> on macOS)

Close tab: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> (also <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> on macOS)

Next tab: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> (also <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⇥</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> on macOS)

Previous tab: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> (also <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⇥</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> on macOS)

---

**Window (split screen within the main Kitty window):**

New window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (also <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↩</kbd> on macOS)

Close window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> (also <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> on macOS)

Next window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Previous window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

After opening a new window (split screen), if you don't like the layout, you can try different layouts by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> until you find a layout that you like.

---

**OS window:**

New OS window: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> (also <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> on macOS)

Comment: `ctrl + shift + t` opens a new tab for me (maybe I added the command to `kitty.conf`). I was looking for something that [splits the screen instead](https://i.imgur.com/fUbzicZ.png). I found that `ctrl + n` achieves this. Again it may be because of something I added to `kitty.conf`, I need to check that.

Comment: @Mr.rk Yes, like I said, `ctrl + shift + t` is supposed to open a new tab. What you need is a new window, which opens with `ctrl + shift + enter` by default.

Comment: Indeed `ctrl + shift + enter` works the same way as `ctrl + n`. Post this as an answer or edit your existing answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mr.rk I have Kitty myself but `ctrl + n` doesn't do anything. I'm working with default settings, so it's probably your own configuration.

Comment: ctrl-shift-enter only splits horizontally, no way to split it vertically it seems.

Comment: @LaoShaw you can add a window (`ctrl + shift + enter`) and then switch the layout with `ctrl + shift + l` ([described in the docs](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/layouts/))

Answer (score 0):

just wanna place more informative docs ([windows](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/overview/#windows)) that helped me find difference in Mac and Windows shortcuts

---

Here two important difference on MacOS. Rest works fine

New window: `cmd + enter`

Close window:
`shift + cmd + d`